# E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I'm try to run sudo apt-get update but I am getting the following error

E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/http could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-http installed?

Can someone please help with the solution. I've tried replacing the source list links with https and when I try to install all the packages I still get the same error

Comment: What is the exact error?